Accessing ASP.NET Core Web API Endpoints with parameters
I am coming across a very strange issue in my application. In my local development I have two endpoints:
namespace APP_API.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ReviewSummaryController : BaseController
    {
        protected IReviewSummaryService _reviewSummaryService;
        public ReviewSummaryController(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<BaseController> logger, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, IReviewSummaryService reviewSummaryService) : base(configuration, logger, httpClientFactory)
        {
            _reviewSummaryService = reviewSummaryService;
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetAllReviewSummary")]
        [Authorize]
        [OktaAllowedRoles(["test-role"])]
        [EnableRateLimiting("api")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
        {
            return Ok(await _reviewSummaryService.GetAllAsync());
        }

        [HttpGet("{userId}")]
        [Authorize]
        [OktaAllowedRoles(["test-role"])]
        [EnableRateLimiting("api")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int userId)
        {
            return Ok(await _reviewSummaryService.GetAsync(userId));
        }
    }
}

In my local environment these both work great. When I deploy this web api to IIS I get
404 Not Found

For any endpoints that are using [HttpGet("{parameter}")] where as [HttpGet(Name = "blah")] works. I noticed this in all of my controllers so that is why I am thinking this is the issue. Is there something additional I need to add to make this routing method work?

The usage of Name and just passing a value are two different things: the first refers to the route name and the second is the route template. The problem you have is because the {parameter} is marked as required. If you don't want it to be, append an ? to it, as in {parameter?}. If you do, you should also add a default to the userId parameter in the method.

But what if I am using the parameter would it still cause this issue? For instance my endpoint I tried was https://api.test.com/api/ReviewSummary/10 and it still fails not found.

Is ReviewSummary the name of the controller?

I updated my code to include the full controller code. Yes its called ReviewSummaryController

It just isnt clear to me why both work locally. Then only one works in production on IIS.

Just for debugging purposes, can you try removing, one by one, the [Authorize], [OktaAllowedRoles(["test-role"])], and [EnableRateLimiting("api")] attributes?

I realize I am a terrible web developer and did something dumb . I was pulling an outdated version of my publish folder. I started to deploy as self contained for some reason and was not using the correct folder to deploy. So much time wasted on something so stupid! I was curious though I was able to do [HttpGet] then do a route tag [route()] in my local testing and that worked but was not sure if I should stick to keeping it in the HttpGet tag vs adding the Route tag. ANy thoughts on that?

HttpGet with a route template should be the same as Route, no need to use the two.

If use only [Route(...)] on an action method, the action would accept all HTTP methods. If use [HttpGet] attributes with additional route template on your action method, which would same as [HttpGet("{userId}")]
